# copy_to_user copies only 4KiB of data to user buffer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have kernel buffer which has the camera frame and want to copy this frame to user buffer.
I will get the user buffer address from application and use "copy_to_user" API to copy the data from kernel address to user address.
But it has the data till 4KiB (0xFF8 -> 4088bytes of data copied) ~4096 (4KiB)

Any help please.

Comment: You have to do DMA to buffer allocated **in user space**. Looks like you didn't get the concept of `copy_to_user()` / `copy_from_user()`. Check *videobuf2* in v4l2 (Video For Linux) framework.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should not do code change in user code but kernel code. user space app would give the address to kernel and kernel should copy the 2MiB camera frame buffer data into user space address, user space app use the same address and it should has the same data which kernel copied. I need to use "get_user_pages" to copy the data to user space address if need more than 4KiB.